# browser sync with ejs, the proxy just loads

Tags: node.js, gulp, ejs, browser-sync

I'm trying to get my MEAN application to work with browser sync. 
I'm using `.ejs` file as template, but whenever I click to open the `index.ejs` file it downloads it.

I tried this two settings in my gulpfile, but none of them works.

```
//this downloads the ejs file
gulp.task('serve', function () {
    browsersync.init({
        server: {
            baseDir: [''],
            directory: true
        }
    });
});

//this just loads and I can't access localhost
gulp.task('serve', function () {
    browsersync.init({
        proxy: 'http://localhost:3000'
    });
});
```

there is a npm package called `browser-sync-ejs`, but the documentation is non existent and I have no idea how to use it.